# Add ifPresernt to Stream

Tags: java

Where should I apply ifPresert() to my stream to Not throw NullPointerExpetion if fax isn't presernt?

```
deptUserMap.get("Collection").stream()
.filter(u->u.getTitle().equals("Tester"))
.findFirst()
.orElse(new User())
.getFax());
```

Comment: can `deptUserMap.get("Collection")` return null?

Comment: My guess is that NPE comes from `u.getTitle().equals("Tester")`, i.e. a user having a null title.

Comment: That's the title of the user, so if there's a bad data in DB, It will return null for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will return null or user fax:

```
Optional<String> userFax = deptUserMap.getOrDefault("Collection", Collections.emptyLis())
 .stream()
.filter(u->Objects.equals("Tester", u.getTitle())) // in case title is null
.findFirst()
.map(User::getFax);
```

Now you can unwrap the Optional, if you need `userFax.orElse(null)`

If you are facing an NPE in first line, that means that there is no 'Collection' key in the deptUserMap map. Since JDK8, you can use [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm getting a Null Pointer at first line

Comment: I have updated the question. As long  as deptUserMap is not null, it will work.

Comment: `"Tester".equals(u.getTitle())` suffices to avoid the NPE.

Comment: Objects.equals() checks for null on both sides, it's safe. Although your option is a bit faster (less null checks)